# Enlarge text height?

Tags: html, css

I have text with font-size 18 and it is displayed in a block style.  I would like to increase the text's "height," in other words, increase how much vertical space the text takes up alone.  I don't want to increase the font size in order to do this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the `line-height` ?

Answer (score 1):

What about line-height Property ?

```
p.small {line-height:90%}
p.big {line-height:200%}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the transform property and scale the height vertically:

**CSS**

```
.stretch {
    transform : scale(1,5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1,5); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1,5); /* IE 9+ */
    -o-transform:scale(1,5); /* Opera */
}
```

Check out this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt844/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `transform`? In particular for your case:

```
-webkit-transform:scale(1,5); /* webkit */
-moz-transform:scale(1,5); /* gecko */
-o-transform:scale(1,5); /* opera */
transform:scale(1,5);
```

As explained here:
http://www.css3files.com/transform/#scale

Comment: That website has loads of useful information, despite the errors. This page in particular reponds to what the OP asks.

Comment: There you go, changed the source website.